# ContentType Phone Call Memo. how to enable Hidden fields?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-column, hidden

when I create a list with Content Type "Phone Call Memo", I get three columns to "work" with in the list-settings:

> "Title", "Append Only Comments" and "Callback Number"

If I edit a view, e.g. "All items". I get plenty more columns to choose from like

> "Call Back", "Confidential", "Date/Time", "Resolved by", ...

If I add those columns to the view, then they are empty and seem read only. I tried adding them with the same name to "Phone Call Memo" and a new child content type of it. In both cases the view offered two columns, e.g. Confidential and Confidential1. How can I enable those fields? They show up in PowerApps as well.

I am using Office 365 with SharePoint Online.

Any help is much appreciated :-)

Dennis

Comment: Are you trying to set some List columns which should be visible when you try to edit a List item?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a workflow on the content type Phone Call Memo
2. First action is Set Workflow Variable
   a.       Create a variable type string
   b.      Fill it with Recipients from the current item (you have no choice in Return field as but that’s no problem)
3. Second action is your email action
   a.       In the To box of the email select the address book icon
   b.      Select in the left side list Workflow Lookup for a user and click Add
   c.       In the next window, select in Data source: Workflow Variables and Parameters
   d.      Select in the Field from source your variable used in the first action
   e.      Select in Return fields as: Email Addresses, Semicolon Delimited

Comment: I am not sure how this relates to my question, I probably just don't get it or expressed my question clear. I try to "activate" those memo fields, instead of creating my own copy of them.